# WordPress won't allow file upload - file cannot be moved to wp-content/uploads

Tags: wordpress, file-permissions

When I try to upload files to the WordPress media library, I get an error saying that file cannot be moved to wp-content/uploads. I tried changing to 777 permissions (just to test) and it still did not work. I tried the following link:

http://2surge.com/how-to-fix-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-error-message/

which says to give the nobody user permission, which did not work.

I also tried adding the following link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-uploads

which says to add FTP connection data to wp-config.php, which did not work.

I tried to upload manually through FTP and then use the Add From Server plugin, however when given the correct connection information to Add From Server (which on other sites I've done with these permissions/ownership isn't even asked for), the plugin cannot connect.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This in Terminal-sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wptest1/wp-content/uploads/2017/07 after creating suitable folders like uploads>2017>07 in wp-content folder in wordpress